# getting the IP address of the miner who mined a block?

Tags: go-ethereum

How do I find out the IP address of the miner who mined the last block, using `geth` ?

Answer (score 1):

Although the IP addresses of nodes are exposed publicly, there is **no** built-in way to determine the IP address of a block miner.

However, block data does reveal the *Ethereum address* of a miner. It could theoretically be possible to trace message propagation and estimate an IP address for a miner based on the first node to broadcast the block. You could then pin this IP to the ethereum address. Unfortunately this still doesn't avoid the problem of proxy nodes.

It's basically infeasible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the address of the miner who found the particular block by using blockchain explorer. https://etherscan.io/blocks

As far as I know, you can't find a particular IP since you can use an address on multiple devices/wallets.